# If I uninstall Terraria on my son's ipad 2 will he lose all his work and worlds done to date?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, games

If I uninstall Terraria on my son's ipad 2 will he lose all his work and worlds done to date? I haven't done anything yet as I want to know before I uninstall if everything will be lost when I reinstall Terraria.

Answer (score 2):

if the game doesn't have the option to save progress to iCloud or "iCloud sync" then yes he will loose all game progress